# Update of chain linked rows

Tags: sql-server

I have table with columns `partija_1`, `partija_2` and `date`.

I should find that `partija_2` is also in column `partija_1` until come 
to `partija_2` that is not in column `partija_1` and take date from it and update previously chain data.

For example 1445033004937 is in `partija_1` and after that I see 1445033003000 that is in `partija_1` and after that 1445033005000 is in `partija_1`. And finally I come to 1445033006000 that is not in `partija_1` and I should take date from it and update date for all columns that are chain linked.

```
Partija_1       Partija_2       date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1445033005038   1445033004937   2016.04.30 should update in 2016.01.31
1445033004937   1445033003000   2016.03.31 should update in 2016.01.31
1445033003000   1445033005000   2016.02.28 should update in 2016.01.31
1445033005000   1445033006000   2016.01.31
5445033005038   5445033004937   2017.04.30 should update in 2017.01.31
5445033004937   5445033003000   2017.03.31 should update in 2017.01.31
5445033003000   5445033005000   2017.02.28 should update in 2017.01.31
5445033005000   5445033006000   2017.01.31
```

Table structure is

```
      create table #test(
Partija_1   varchar(40),
Partija_2   varchar(40),
date varchar(40)
)
```

Values in table #test are:

```
insert into #test
values('1445033005038','1445033004937','2016.04.30')
insert into #test
values('1445033004937','1445033003000','2016.03.31')
insert into #test
values('1445033003000','1445033005000','2016.02.28')
insert into #test
values('1445033005000','1445033006000','2016.01.31')
insert into #test
values('5445033005038','5445033004937','2017.04.30')
insert into #test
values('5445033004937','5445033003000','2017.03.31')
insert into #test
values('5445033003000','5445033005000','2017.02.28')
insert into #test
values('5445033005000','5445033006000','2017.01.31')
                                                                                                                 Result should be update date column, and output should be the following:                                                                                            
  Partija 1     Partija 2         date
1445033005038   1445033004937   2016.01.31
1445033004937   1445033003000   2016.01.31
1445033003000   1445033005000   2016.01.31
1445033005000   1445033006000   2016.01.31
5445033005038   5445033004937   2017.01.31
5445033004937   5445033003000   2017.01.31
5445033003000   5445033005000   2017.01.31
5445033005000   5445033006000   2017.01.31
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I can't make heads or tails of what you are trying to do here. Perhaps you should post your table definition and some sample data. And then post what the desired output should be. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Like @SeanLange I am having trouble deciphering what you're doing here. But it sounds like you might want to use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to get the data from the previous row to update the current row.